# Using definesPresentationContext with UIModalPresentationStyle.custom

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle, uipresentationcontroller

I am using view controller containment to manage a set of child view controllers which should be able to modally present other view controllers in a *custom* manner.

I have run into an issue where the `definesPresentationContext` property is *not used* when a presenting from a view controller using `UIModalPresentationStyle.custom`

As an example, I have three view controllers: `ROOT`, `A`, and `B`

```
ROOT
 |_ A
```

`A` is the child of `ROOT`. I would like to present `B` modally from `A` while using custom `UIPresentationController`, `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

So I do the following inside the code for controller `A` (note controller `A` has `definesPresentationContext` set to `true`):

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any?) {
    let presentationController = MyCustomPresentation()

    let controllerToPresent = B()

    controllerToPresent.modalTransitionStyle = .custom
    controllerToPresent.transitioningDelegate = presentationController

    present(controllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, inside my presentation controller (which is also my `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`) I encounter the following problem:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)

    if let fromVC = fromVC as? A,
        let toVC = toVC as? B {
        //Do the presentation from A to B
    }
}
```

In this function, where I expect `fromVC` to be of type `A`, it is actually `ROOT`. Despite the fact that `A` specifies `definesPresentationContext`.

So I figure this is because I'm using `UIModalPresentationStyle.custom`. So I change it to `UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext`

This causes iOS to correctly read the `definesPresentationContext` property from `A`, and my `animateTransition` function now gets called with the correct from view controller, but:

Because my modal presentation style is no longer `.custom`, the following method in my transitioning delegate **no longer gets called**

```
func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?
```

So my presentation controller becomes unused.

I want a `.custom` modal transition style which respects `definesPresentationContext`. Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Basically, I want a custom modal presentation within the current context.

Comment: Have you tried setting the transitioning delegate also in `A`?
Before this line:

`present(controllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)`.

try this:

`self.transitioningDelegate = presentationController`

I suggest this when using: `UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext`

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIPresentationController` subclass, override `shouldPresentInFullscreen` as follows:

```
 override var shouldPresentInFullscreen: Bool {
     get {
         return false
     }
 }
```

As per the `UIPresentationController` header:

```
// By default each new presentation is full screen.
// This behavior can be overriden with the following method to force a current context presentation.
// (Default: YES)
@property(nonatomic, readonly) BOOL shouldPresentInFullscreen;
```

This along with `definesPresentationContext` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked my UIPresentationController subclass and found it was already returning `false` for `shouldPresentInFullscreen` — but it's still not given the view controller further down the tree defining the presentation context, and getting the root vc instead.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Right now I assume that `definesPresentationContext ` does not work with `UIModalPresentationStyle.custom`